# All shell scripts dropping back to command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

I'm probably doing something remarkably stupid, but I can't figure out what.

Running Ubuntu Server 12.04 on a cloud host (Digital Ocean, if it matters). All shell scripts do absolutely nothing and just return immediately to the prompt, without error, warning or even a wag of the middle finger.

- start-stop-daemons scripts will not run from command line with "./script-name", not just cron
- execute bit is set
- shell is /bin/bash
- user is root
- tried changing #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash
- tried not using dash by `dpkg-reconfigure dash`
- scripts are being parsed -- if I edit it to something illegal, I get errors

Running out of ideas...

Is there some reason I just wouldn't be seeing the output?

Comment: Can you execute `strace -f`, its output might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to debug the shell script, here is how

Put that after the #!/bin/bash line

```
logfile=/tmp/script.log
exec > $logfile 2>&1
```

then execute the script with this command from shell prompt.

```
# bash -x script-name.sh
```

See what happens next, check to see if the commands written in script are getting executed.

Also double check the path using this commnad.

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. My binaries had somehow migrated from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin` and all the scripts just happened to be failing without warning.